# cURL hanging for 15 seconds when sending HEAD requests

Tags: curl, http-headers, wget, http-head

### Background

I've been timing some HTTP requests via the CLI using `time` and tools such as `wget` and `curl` as follows:

`/usr/bin/time -v wget --spider http://localhost/index`
`/usr/bin/time -v curl http://localhost/index 2>&1 > /dev/null`

What I noticed is that when using `curl`, I was getting similar response times as with `wget` only on the first request, and much lower times on subsequent requests, as if the responses to `curl` were served from cache and `wget` were not.

After investigating I found out that when specifying `--spider`, `wget` issues a `HEAD` request as appended below which could explain why the cache is bypassed with `wget`:

*Request*

```
HEAD /index HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

*Response*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2011 14:45:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Content-Location: index.php
Vary: negotiate,Accept-Encoding
TCN: choice
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10
Set-Cookie: SESS421aa90e079fa326b6494f812ad13e79=16oqmug3loekjlb1tlvmsrtcr2; expires=Wed, 21-Dec-2011 18:19:19 GMT; path=/
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Nov 2011 14:45:59 GMT
Cache-Control: store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Since I'm doing more advanced stuff (writing body and headers in separate files, posting data, saving cookie in jar...) I need to use `curl` instead of `wget`. Therefore I'm trying to emulate a `HEAD` request with `curl`.

### Issue

I managed to send a `HEAD` request with `curl` as follows:

`curl "http://localhost/index" --request "HEAD" -H "Connection: Keep-Alive" -0`

*Request*

```
HEAD /index HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

*Response*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2011 15:44:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Content-Location: index.php
Vary: negotiate,Accept-Encoding
TCN: choice
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10
Set-Cookie: SESS421aa90e079fa326b6494f812ad13e79=4001hcmhdbnkb9e2v8nok9lii1; expires=Wed, 21-Dec-2011 19:17:22 GMT; path=/
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Nov 2011 15:44:02 GMT
Cache-Control: store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Despite the request/response being seemingly OK, when I execute the above `curl` command while sniffing with `tcpdump` I can see that the server responds straight away, however *my `curl` command always stays hanging for exactly 15 seconds* which is obviously a big issue since I'm trying to time my `curl` command (FYI before I used to get a `curl: (18) transfer closed with 3 bytes remaining to read` when the server was not handling `HEAD` properly and was returning `Content-Length: 3` without returning any content, but no everything looks OK).

I tried to play with the `--max-time` and `--speed-time` arguments to have `curl` timeout immediately upon receiving the `200 OK` but it makes no difference.

**Q: How can I send a `HEAD` request with curl in a way that the curl command stops immediately upon receiving the response from the server?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why don't you just use the `-I` option?

```
-I/--head
    (HTTP/FTP/FILE) Fetch the HTTP-header only! HTTP-servers feature
    the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but  the  header
    of  a  document.  When used on a FTP or FILE file, curl displays
    the file size and last modification time only
```

Comment: because I was unaware of the option :) Great, that does the trick: sends a `HEAD` command and stops as soon as it receives the headers like with `wget --spider`.

Comment: A more general option (not curl-specific) is to send the "Connection: close" header... not keep-alive. The -I flag causes curl to short-circuit itself and closes the connection itself. "Connection: close" tells the server to close the connection after handling the request. "keep-alive" tells it to wait for more requests. :)