# Why does curl not work, but wget works?

Tags: http, curl, wget

I am using both curl and wget to get this url: http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/01/19/118675/

For curl, it returns no output at all, but with wget, it returns the entire HTML source:

Here are the 2 commands. I've used the same user agent, and both are coming from the same IP, and are following redirects. The URL is exactly the same. For curl, it returns immediately after 1 second, so I know it's not a timeout issue.

```
curl -L -s "http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/01/19/118675/" --max-redirs 10000 --location --connect-timeout 20 -m 20 -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" 2>&1

wget http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/01/19/118675/ --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
```

If NY Times might be cloaking, and not returning the source to curl, what could be different in the headers curl is sending? I assumed since the user agent is the same, the request should look exactly the same from both of these requests. What other "footprints" should I check?

Comment: this one would help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298727/curl-hanging-for-15-seconds-when-sending-head-requests

Comment: doesnt helpt at all :(

Comment: I suggest adding the `-v` flag to your curl request to show you everything that is going on. The `-d` flag added to your wget request shows you what is happening with the successful wget request. Both programs are redirected to a login page, but somehow wget successfully retrieves the target resource, but curl is continuously redirected until it gets a bad redirection and gives up. From a brief look at the output, it looks like wget is properly sending cookies back to nytimes.com while curl is never sending any cookies back.

Comment: Try using `-c cookie.txt` with your `curl` and optionally use `-b RMID`.

Comment: Thanks, sending cookies works. What does -b RMID do?

Comment: It forces sending an empty `RMID` cookie.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The way to solve is to analyze your `curl` request by doing `curl -v ...` and your wget request by doing `wget -d ...` which shows that curl is redirected to a login page

```
> GET /2012/01/19/118675/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
> Host: opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
< Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2014 03:23:06 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Location: http://www.nytimes.com/glogin?URI=http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/01/19/118675/&OQ=_rQ3D0&OP=1b5c69eQ2FCinbCQ5DzLCaaaCvLgqCPhKP
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

followed by a loop of redirections (which you must have noticed, because you have already set the --max-redirs flag).

On the other hand, `wget` follows the same sequence except that it returns the cookie set by nytimes.com with its subsequent request(s)

```
---request begin---
GET /2012/01/19/118675/?_r=0 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept: */*
Host: opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: NYT-S=0MhLY3awSMyxXDXrmvxADeHDiNOMaMEZFGdeFz9JchiAIUFL2BEX5FWcV.Ynx4rkFI
```

The request sent by curl never includes the cookie.

The easiest way I see to modify your curl command and obtain the desired resource is by adding `-c cookiefile` to your curl command. This stores the cookie in the otherwise unused temporary "cookie jar" file called "cookiefile" thereby enabling curl to send the needed cookie(s) with its subsequent requests.

For example, I added the flag `-c x` directly after "curl " and I obtained the output just like from wget (except that wget writes it to a file and curl prints it on STDOUT).

Comment: -v is usually very helpful

Answer (score 0):

In my case was because the https_proxy enviroment variable for utility cURL needs set the port in the URL, for example :

Not work with cURL :
https_proxy=http://proxyapp.net.com/

Works with cURL :
https_proxy=http://proxyapp.net.com:80/

With "wget" utility works with and without the port in url, but curl needs it, in case of not set the utility "curl" return error "(56) Proxy CONNECT aborted".

When you get verbosity of the command "curl -v" could see "curl" use port "1080" as default if port in not set at proxy url.