# cant crawl url with curl

Tags: php, curl

Tried to crawl this ny times article with Curl:  [Article](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/07/16/world/middleeast/israel-gaza-strip.html)

the function

```
function get_content_curl($url) {
   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   return $data;
}
```

He fails to crawl the article redirecting to a login page and crawl the login page but not the article. why?

how to prevent redirecting? i also tried `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false` but dosent work. how to fix this?

**Answer of my own question:**

Added those 2 lines for creating and reading the cookies and it works.

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986395/why-does-curl-not-work-but-wget-works I think this can help!

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);   could help you get some useful debugging information