# Do a head request with curl (-I option) using PHP

Tags: php, curl

Using PHP, I want to do a [head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301492/1185126) request of curl **-I** option.

This is how I do a normal curl request:

```
   $url = 'https://domain.com';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

How can I add the head -I option?

Answer (score 0):

I generally do something like :

```
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
```

Then:

```
$rawResult= curl_exec ( $ch);        
$info = curl_getinfo ( $ch);                
$responseHeader = substr($rawResult, 0, $info['header_size']);        
$responseBody = substr( $rawResult, $info['header_size'] );
```

If you add `CURLOPT_NOBODY` you will have an empty `$responseBody`(probably, not tried it).

Comment: Not only probably, CURLOPT_NOBODY will produce a HEAD request - which answers the question...